# MarkerClusterGroup not displaying locations that are stored on ref value in Vue 3

Tags: leaflet, vuejs3

I tried to map the values of my ref variable and then put it into leaflet markers. But to no avail, no clusters were displaying on the map. See below code for reference. Thank you!

```
const geoLocations = ref([])
async function getHeatMapLocations() 
{
   const res = await    axios.get('dashboard/security-alerts-map')
   geoLocations.value = res.data
}

geoLocations.value.map(function (markerElem: any) {
      const marker = leaflet.marker(
        {
          lat: parseFloat(markerElem.alert_lat),
          lng: parseFloat(markerElem.alert_long),
        },
        {
          title: markerElem.alert_country,
          icon: leaflet.icon({
            iconUrl: `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${mapMarkerSvg}`,
            iconAnchor: leaflet.point(10, 35),
          }),
        }
      );
      markers.addLayer(marker);

      
    });

map.addLayer(markers)

I am using MarkerClusterGroup

NOTE: There will be a chance that coordinates will be the same.
```